# urldecode losses 1 parameter

Tags: php, urlencode, urldecode

I'm using urlencode & urldecode to pass variables trough a html-form.

```
$info = 'tempId='.$rows['tempID'].'&tempType='.$rows['tempType'].'&dbId='.$rows['ID'];
echo '<input type="hidden" name="rank[]" value="'.urlencode($info).'" >';
```

Here is what is in $rows

```
array (size=4)
  'ID' => string '110' (length=3)
  'tempID' => string '1' (length=1)
  'tempType' => string 'temp_first' (length=10)
  'pageOrder' => string '0' (length=1)
```

So $info is

```
tempId=1&tempType=temp_first&dbId=110
```

But if i then decode it, it losses 1 parameter. How is this possible?

```
foreach (explode('&', urldecode($list[$i])) as $chunk) {
    $param = explode("=", $chunk);

    $tempId = urldecode($param[0]); // template id
    $tempType = urldecode($param[1]); // Template type
    $dbId = urldecode($param[2]); // database ID

    var_dump($param);

}
```

Output:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => string 'dbId' (length=4)
  1 => string '110' (length=3)
```

Sometime there are even things in the array wich should not be in there, for example instead of temp_first it says tempType. Just the variable name.

I hope you guys can help me

Comment: You know that with jQuery, $info is automatically decoded and put into $_POST variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need to explode and process the string manually, you can use [`parse_str()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php):

```
parse_str(urldecode($list[$i]), $output);
var_dump($output);
```

Would output:

```
array
  'tempId' => string '1' (length=1)
  'tempType' => string 'temp_first' (length=10)
  'dbId' => string '110' (length=3)
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
  $result=array();
  foreach (explode('&', urldecode($list[$i])) as $chunk) {
     $param = explode("=", $chunk);
     $result[$param[0]]=$param[1];
  } 
  var_dump($result);
```

Comment: There's no need to loop and explode, see [`parse_str()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php)

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this and check the result (I'm groping in the dark though):

```
//change this <input type="hidden" name="rank[]" value="'.urlencode($info).'" > to
//<input type="hidden" name="urlargs" value="'.urlencode($info).'" >
$values = explode('&',urldecode($_POST['urlargs']));
$arguments = array();
foreach($values as $argument_set){
    $data = explode('=',$argument_set);
    $arguments[$data[0]] = $data[1];
}
var_dump($arguments);
```

I believe the problem is in the way you're processing the value

Answer (score 0):

```
$data=array();
foreach (explode('&', urldecode($list[$i])) as $chunk) {

    $param = explode("=", $chunk); //
    $data[$param[0]]=$param[1]

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of grouping all code together, start by putting it in seperate vars and echo the content for debugging. Because you are saying you loose one variable, but the output you show is just one of the variables. What is the var_dump of the other two?

Because your `var_dump($param);` would output the part before the '=' and after the '=', so indeed i would expect the output to be something like: So which one of these are you missing?

```
array (size=2)
  0 => string 'tempId' (length=6)
  1 => string '1' (length=1)

array (size=2)
  0 => string 'tempType' (length=8)
  1 => string 'temp_first' (length=10)

array (size=2)
  0 => string 'dbId' (length=4)
  1 => string '110' (length=3)
```

DEBUG code:

```
foreach ($list as $row) {
  echo 'Full row:: '. $row.'<br>';

  //if the data is comming via GET or POST, its already decoded and no need to do it again
  $split = explode('&', urldecode($row));

  foreach($split as $chunk) {
    echo 'Chunk:: '.$chunk.'<br>';

    $param = explode('=', $chunk);

    echo 'param name:: '.$param[0].'<br>';
    echo 'param value:: '.$param[1].'<br>';
  }
}
```